# LSTM output Dense expects 2d input

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I have features in shape of (size,2) and labels in shape of (size,1) i.e. for [x,y] in feature the label will be z. I want to build an LSTM in keras that can do such job since the feature is linked somehow with the previous inputs i.e. 1 or multiple(I believe its a hyperparameter).

Sample dataset values are:-

```
features     labels

[1,2]         [5]

[3,4]         [84]
```

Here is what I have done so far:-

```
print(labels.shape)     #prints (1414,2)
print(features.shape)   #prints(1414,1)
look_back=2

# reshape input to be [samples, time steps, features]
features = np.reshape(features, (features.shape[0], 1, features.shape[1]))
labels = np.reshape(labels, (labels.shape[0], 1, 1))

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features,labels,test_size=0.2)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape=(1, look_back)))   #executing correctly
model.add(Dense(1))    #error here is "ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (1131, 1, 1)"
model.summary()
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=1, verbose=2)
```

So can anyone please help me build a minimal LSTM example to run my code? Thank you. I don't know how can dense layer have 2 dimensions I mean it is an integer telling how many units to use in the dense layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must not reshape your labels.

Try this:

```
features = np.reshape(features, (features.shape[0], 1, features.shape[1]))

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape=(1, features.shape[1])))  
model.add(Dense(1))    
model.summary()
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=1, verbose=2)
```

Comment: What if my labels are in shape of (1414,100). Then also I shouldn't reshape? How will dense layer work then?